# Where is the Ford Fiesta 2011 speed sensor located?

Tags: ford, speedometer, fiesta, elm-327, wheel-speed-sensor

I have a Ford Fiesta 2011 and the speed meter was sporadically failing (speed would drop to zero with the car moving and sometimes get back to normal). The yellow warning lamp was lit and I could confirm there's something wrong with it by using an ELM327 adapter and the Android App "Torque", which displayed the following error: "P0500 - Transmission: Vehicle Speed Sensor". I wanted to locate where this sensor is located to check if I can do something about it, but I have no idea where does it run through the car. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speed sensor should be located on the outside of the transmission housing on the passenger side. [Looks like this.](https://www.ebay.com/itm/2011-FORD-FIESTA-SE-1-6L-4-CYL-FWD-OEM-AUTOMATIC-TRANSMISSION-SHAFT-SPEED-SENSOR/152569424109)

EDIT:
Also found a diagram to repair the DPS6 transmission. This is where the speed sensors are located. Its a bit confusing as it assumes you have the transmission pulled out, but I hope it helps.
[image]