# 2011 Ford fiesta 1.6l manual transmission

Tags: ford, manual-transmission, fiesta, vehicle-speed-sensor

I have a 2011 ford fiesta 1.6l manual 5 speed. My speedometer is working good but odometer  and all other attached infos like the shift light, the miles per gallons  or distance left to empty does not work. I bought the transmission speed sensor but cant locate it. Any ideas where it should be?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Do you mean ‘odometer’ or ‘tachometer’?

Comment: If the speedo is working then a transmission speed sensor is unlikely to correct the problem.  Sounds like an ECU issue to me.  The transmission speed sensor sends a signal to the ECU which then calculates all the other things you mentioned and displays them.

Comment: Is this related to https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/55866/where-is-the-ford-fiesta-2011-speed-sensor-located?